# Is there a way to embed local (i.e., not in SharePoint) Microsoft Office documents in a Blazor server application for viewing?

Tags: blazor, ms-office

I am working on a web-based application for users to view documents (e.g., .pdf, .txt, .csv, .png, .jpg, .xlsx, .docx, etc.).

Currently I am creating an `<iframe>` element with the "local" path as the source, but this is not working for any of the Microsoft Office documents.

I do not need to let the users edit the document at all, I just need to let them view the documents.

At this point, I am willing to accept a solution where I convert the Microsoft Office document to .PDF for viewing.

Is there a way to do this in a Blazor server application, preferably **without** a third-party plugin?

### Edit

I have found `Microsoft.Office.Interop` but I cannot figure out if this will let me do what I need to do or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how your app is architected, if it's a Blazor Server app then the files available to the Blazor backend are on the Web Server, not the users machine, are they running your app localy?

Can't help with embedding Word directly into a page without using something like Syncfusion components.  I think this would have been possible in I.E.'s day with something like an ActiveX control, but not so sure now.

I can tell you how to use Word Interop to save a document as PDF though.

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
string input = @"C:\inputFile.docx", //Full Path as I think Word will assume your My Documents folder, not the working folder of your app.
       output = @"C:\output.pdf";

var app = new Application();

try
{
    app.Visible = false;
    app.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

    var inputDocument = app.Documents.Open(input, ReadOnly: true, AddToRecentFiles: false);
    inputDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(output, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport: false);

    inputDocument.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

    app.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
}
finally
{
    app.Quit(SaveChanges: WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
}
```

Comment: What package is `Application` from? My VisualStudio is not resolving anything.

Comment: I thought you already had the interop stuff running. It's in the namespace "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" you need to add a COM reference to a version of Microsoft Word Object Library.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I have absolutely nothing running. I just saw the Interop stuff while looking around the web for a way to display Microsoft Office documents within my Blazor app.

Comment: So, I have added the NuGet packages: Microsoft.Office.Interop, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word all for Office "2013/2016/2019", but when I try to execute your solution, I get an error: `Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.` The Office version I am using is 2016.

Comment: It's not a NuGet package, you need to add a COM reference, you will only have this reference available if you have Word installed already.

Comment: Com refrence will be something like 'Microsoft Word XX Object Library'

Comment: I cannot use that  either, as this will be deployed in Docker on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Documents](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cembed-a-document-spreadsheet-or-presentation), look at the **Embed files** section. After you upload the file you can publish it as embedded. This will give you an iframe to embed into Blazor. I like this route because you don't need any third party libraries and Google handles the grunt work.

If the user is providing the files and not you than you could use the Google [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#.net) to upload the file, it will return a `FileId`. Use the api to publish the file and make the iframe yourself by adding `/pub?embedded=true` to the url.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FileId/pub?embedded=true
```

Comment: Can't use Google Documents ... thank you.